# Swift: How to replace a substring with regular expression

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I could not find a good way to replace a string using regular expression in swift. My web service returns string which may contain multiple unicode characters like in the string

> V&#x0307;E TOT

How can we replace the string "&#x0307;" with "\u{0307}" to display on a iOS label.

Comment: @rmaddy: The answer helped me to properly handle unicode characters display. But in general I was looking for a good way to find a replace using regular expressions in swift.

Comment: Why would you use a regular expression?

Comment: @rmaddy: As an example replacing matching curly braces with square braces using regular expression. ex. convert from {abc} xyz} {uvw} to [abc] xyz} [uvw]

Comment: That's a completely different question than what you originally posted here. If you have a new question, post a new question with all relevant details. Make sure you include your attempts.